# ImportError loading spacy in jupyter notebook(ubuntu)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spacy, spacy-transformers

I got a problem I can't seem to figure out. The first time I imported Spacy into a Jupyter notebook I had no problems. It just imported it as I expected.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

i tried

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

and i got this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-e4c801bd61f2> in <module>
----> 1 import spacy
      2 nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

~/Downloads/PREFIX=/home/khbe0387/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py in <module>
      9 
     10 # These are imported as part of the API
---> 11 from thinc.api import prefer_gpu, require_gpu, require_cpu  # noqa: F401
     12 from thinc.api import Config
     13 

ImportError: cannot import name 'prefer_gpu' from 'thinc.api' (/home/khbe0387/Downloads/PREFIX=/home/khbe0387/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thinc/api.py)
```

Comment: Sounds like you got an old version of Thinc somehow. Can you start over in a clean environment and install spaCy from scratch?

Comment: how can clean all envirionment from jupyternotebook

Comment: It looks like you're using conda, so you should create a new environment to work in. Learning how this works will take a little bit but it's important. https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: how can i now install spacy from scratch ????

Comment: Please follow the official instructions. https://spacy.io/usage

Comment: python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm  i got invalid syntax

Comment: In a notebook you have to preface shell commands with `!`, like `!python -m spacy download` etc...

Comment: and now i got module 'spacy' has no attribute 'load'